# Error "No se encontró Python"

Tags: python, aplicación-web, windows10

Código:

```
from flask import flask

app = Flask(_name_)

if _name_ == '_main_':

 app.run(port = 3000, debug = True)
```

Error:

No se encontró Python; ejecuta sin argumentos para instalar desde Microsoft Store o deshabilita este acceso directo en Configuración > Administrar los alias de ejecución de las aplicaciones

Comment: Si tienes python instalado?, habré un cmd y ejecuta `python --version` y si obtienes un error deberías ver la configuración de las variables de entorno

Comment: Instala Python desde la web oficial: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/. Para ejecutar tu programa, abre la carpeta que lo contiene, CTRL+L para situarte en la barra de dirección, escribe `cmd` y presiona Enter. En la terminal que se abre, `python nombredelprograma.py` y Enter.